# I'm trying to create a Slackbot (which responds when I press a button) using Google spreadsheet, but I'm getting an error

Tags: javascript, button, bots, spreadsheet, slack

I'm going to use Google spreadsheets to make slacks
I'm going to make a bot to check for approval.

But there's an error..
I want to solve it, but... I don't know what the hell is wrong.

Seeing that it doesn't work by pressing the button, I wonder why Sleck can't deliver parameters to AppScript...

So how do we solve this?

```
Original Code
const googleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = googleSheet.getSheetByName('sheet1');
const sheetLastrow = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
function myFunction() {
for(i=3; i<=sheetLastrow; i++){
var payload = {
"channel": sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue(),
"text":"Hi" + sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue()
"attachments": [
{
"fallback" : "Do you want to approve?",
"title": "Do you want to approve?",
"callback_id": "approve",
"color": "#3AA3E3",
"attachment_type": "default",
"actions": [
{
"name": "approve",
"text": "accept",
"type": "button",
"style": "primary",
"value": "accept"  
},
{
"name": "approve",
"text": "reject",
"type": "button",
"style": "danger",
"value": "reject"  
}  
]
}
]
};
var options = {
"method": "post"
"headers": {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + "slack token",
"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
},
"payload": JSON.stringify(payload)  
};
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", options);
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
console.log(data);
}
}
function doPost(e) {
var parameter=e.parameter;
var data = parameter.payload;
var json = JSON.parse(data);

if(json.actions[0].name == "approve"){
var choice = json.actions[0].value;
var choiceID = json.user.id;
writeSheet(choice,choiceID);
}
var replyMessage = {
"replace_original": true,
"response_type": "in_channel",
"text": " *" + json.actions[0].value
};
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(replyMessage)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
function writeSheet(choice,choiceID){
for(i=3; i<=sheetLastrow; i++){
var id = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
if(choiceID==id){
sheet.getRange(i,5).setValue(choice);
}
}
}
```

error message

Errorbody {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') (line 62, file "Code")